# amazon seller account message fetching way

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I want to pull the messages that I am getting in my amazon seller central account, and I want to reply them manually. I have checked amazon mws API's but I can find such API to pull and push messages.

But there are some third-party applications that deal with these things like https://www.replymanager.com/

we can integrate Amazon seller account, then we get all messages in reply manager and we can reply too.

If Amazon provides no API then how https://www.replymanager.com/ works??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't managing anything via an API.

Amazon lets you manage customer service messages via an email address that you supply seller central (check notification preferences maybe?)

Reply manager manages email replies.

Comment: Thanks , i think so. When we setup reply manager they provide 1 email that we need to set in amazon seller centeral.